# state machine modeling for pm

Tags: modeling, state-machine

Let's say we have an FSM for a private message. Let's take a look what happens when it enters the state `delivered`. What do you think of the following approaches or is there a different one?

1. Have 3 states: `delivered`, `unread` and `read`. Move automatically to the state `unread`.
2. Have 2 states: `delivered` and `read`. Stay in the state `delivered` and assume that it's unread. Move to
   state `read` when necessary.

Comments:

1. Is that a good idea? It makes the state `delivered` seem
   superfluous.
2. At first it seems that we've saved a state. Imagine if we provide
   functionality "mark as unread". Should we move from `read` back to
   `delivered`? This seems a little counter-intuitive from a
   developer's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Noting that you automatically move out of delivered, you're correct that that state is superfluous. Therefore, it's easy to optimize a meaningless state out. After all, delivered just means that you're in this FSM at all.

If you have a read message, and you mark it as unread, just move it back to unread. That's what the button means, and you can treat it intuitively. So, just simplify your system to two states (a single bit).